# How to show and hide rows using several select buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

I have problem with showing and hiding rows, when I select two select buttons at once.

Using only one button, I can show/hide the correct rows.
Using both buttons at once, no rows will be displayed.

Where is the logical error in the code?

Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/83/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>  
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="showNew=false" ng-click="showNew =! showNew"><span> Show new only</span> <br>   
<input type="checkbox" ng-init="showOld=false" ng-click="showOld =! showOld"><span> Show old only </span> 
    </p>

    <table border="1">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="{'newp':person.newp, 'oldp':person.oldp}" 
            ng-hide="(!person.newp && showNew) || (!person.oldp && showOld)">

            <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.city }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: OK. I have a simple (!) solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/85/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comparator in your filter:

`ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:{newp:showNew, oldp:showOld}:showTest"`

and in controller set comparison function:

```
$scope.showTest = function(actual, expected){
        if(!$scope.showNew && !$scope.showOld)
            return true;
        return angular.equals(expected, actual);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D79F7/2/

Comment: Your approach is quite clean but the list disappears when both the checkboxes are checked. May be you can try to fix that.

Comment: When both the checkboxes are checked, only new and old users should be visible. I mean only the users in green and red and not black.

Comment: @ng-User Yes, you right. In this case, comparator useless, but it can be implemented even shorter function:
`ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:showTest"` and `$scope.showTest = function(item){       
        if(!$scope.showNew && !$scope.showOld) return true;
        if($scope.showNew && $scope.showOld) return item.newp || item.oldp;
        return ($scope.showNew && item.newp) || ($scope.showOld && item.oldp);
    }    `
http://jsfiddle.net/sH9RJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom filter:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showNew">..Show new only..
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showOld">..Show old only..
..        
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons | personsFilter : showNew : showOld" ..>
```

JS

```
myApp.filter("personsFilter",function(){
    return function(input, showNew, showOld){        
        if(!showNew && !showOld){
            return input;
        }
        else if(showNew && !showOld){
            var temp = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if(input[i].newp && !input[i].oldp)
                    temp.push(input[i]);                
            }
            return temp;
        }
        else if(showOld && !showNew){
            var temp = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if(input[i].oldp && !input[i].newp)
                    temp.push(input[i]);                
            }
            return temp;
        }
        else if(showOld && showNew){
            var temp = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if(input[i].oldp || input[i].newp)
                    temp.push(input[i]);                
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/87/)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. Thats it what I wanted. To realize it with show/hide was very complicated ^^. Thanks a lot CodeHater

Comment: @ng-User My solution is much shorter. There is no need to use a custom filter. You can use comporator function: http://jsfiddle.net/D79F7/2/.

Comment: @ng-User I liked the solution using `ng-show` more. Anyway, you can update your question asking for a solution using a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your boolean expression:
Correctly as follows:

`ng-hide="(!person.newp && showNew ) || (!person.oldp && showOld)"`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWy93/2/

Comment: thanks. I found a solution. But meanwhile I am trying to resolve it with filter (incl. both buttons) intead of "show" or "hide". Would be great if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Thanks Oledje.
Unfortunately I only can show one group (none, new, old) But my purpose is: 
both buttons selected --> show old, show new, hide none ////
no button is selected --> show all groups.